# How to make a spatial heatmap in R (neuroscience plots)

Tags: r

I want to make a spatial heat map of some neurobiological data, very much like figure e here:

[image]

The data I have look like this:

```
Time    Centre posn X   Centre posn Y   In white    In striped
00:00.0         0   1
00:00.2 414 267 0   1
00:00.3 411 268 0   1
00:00.5 410 270 0   1
00:00.6 410 270 0   1
00:00.7 409 270 0   1
00:00.8 409 273 0   1
00:00.9 412 271 0   1
00:01.0 412 271 0   1
00:01.1 411 271 0   1
00:01.3 409 273 0   1
00:01.4 407 276 0   1
00:01.5 409 274 0   1
00:01.7 406 276 0   1
00:01.8 408 274 0   1
00:01.9 405 276 0   1
00:02.0 405 276 0   1
00:02.1 406 275 0   1
```

What is the best way to produce that kind of heatmap in R? I've been trying `stat_density_2d` but it doesn't give me what I'm looking for. It shows the areas of high density but leaves the low density areas blank.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
x_coord <- c(1,2,3,4)
y_coord <- c(1,2,3,4)
value <- c(12,15,19,30)
foo <- data.frame(x_coord, y_coord, value)
library(MBA)
foo=foo[ order(foo[,1], foo[,2],foo[,3]), ]
mba.int <- mba.surf(foo, 300, 300, extend=T)$xyz.est
library(fields)
fields::image.plot(mba.int)
```